# ¿Por qué "estar en la parra" quiere decir estar despistado?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

> - Juan, ¿has traído los cedés de Joselito que te pedí?
>   - Caramba, no, se me ha olvidado.
>   - Anda que... **estás en la parra**.

Como veis, en España utilizamos *estar en la parra* para identificar el estado de alguien que es (o está) despistado.

El DRAE recoge alguna acepción idiomática *subirse a la parra* en su entrada de *parra*:

> [**parra<sup>1</sup>**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RyYokGJ%7CRyZdqBQ)
>   Quizá del gót. *parra, -ans 'cercado, enrejado'.
>   *subirse alguien a la parra*
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. Darse importancia, enorgullecerse.
>   2. loc. verb. coloq. Tomarse atribuciones que no le corresponden.
>   3. loc. verb. coloq. montar en cólera.

Pero no recoge esta que menciono yo. Por tanto, me surge la duda del origen de tal divertida expresión. ¿Se conoce en otras regiones? ¿Se usa en otras países hispanohablantes?

Como curiosidad, añado alguna otra forma también usada por aquí:

- [*Estar en Babia*](http://babia.net/2011/del-nombre-de-babia)
- *Estar en la luna de Valencia*
- *Estar empanado*

Comment: En Chile se usa simplemente como *estás en otra.*

Comment: Y los mas viejos en Chile también decimos _estás en la Luna_.

Comment: En Andalucía se conoce y usa la expresión _estar en la parra_. Ya puestos a buscar otras opciones, tienes _estar en la higuera_, _estar en la inopia_, _estar pensando en la musarañas_...

Comment: Yo no lo había oído. Con el mismo significado existe la expresión estar a uvas. Puede que tengan el mismo origen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que *la parra* que se menciona sí que se refiere al árbol. Sin embargo, el dicho no tiene que ver con el vino. Una parra se suele poner en alto para que la uva se estropee menos (mi suegro tiene una así, sin ir más lejos). Por tanto, si te subes a la parra estás en una posición ventajosa para coger la mejor uva, de ahí el significado que ves en la RAE. A partir de ahí, si te quedas mucho tiempo arriba empiezas a perder la noción de lo que pasa a tu alrededor, y entonces es cuando *estar en la parra* adquiere un significado similar a *[estar en la higuera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KNmlooy)*, que es lo mismo que estar en Babia. Curiosamente, también puedes caerte de la parra, o [de la higuera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KNmlooy) cuando por fin te das cuenta de lo que pasa a tu alrededor.

Lo que ignoro es por qué las expresiones con higuera están recogidas por la RAE, pero no así las de la parra. Puede que, sencillamente, sea una expresión demasiado localizada y se conozca únicamente en algunas regiones de España.

Comment: Caramba, qué interesante ver cómo una expresión tiene dos significados en función del tiempo que te pases en la parra. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

En esta ocasión parra hace alusión a la vid, o a un viñedo. Dado que el vino se produce de la vid, estar en la parra es una **metáfora** que hace alusión a alguien mareado (por estar en una parra y se sobrentiende que bebiendo vino) y se ha quedado despistado por hacerlo.

Comment: No conozco el dicho pero me parece lógico lo que afirmas. En ese caso parece que no es una metáfora sino una metonimia (porque el vino es el producto la parra).

Comment: Suena lógico, pero yo me lo tomaría con cautela. Sobre todo, teniendo en cuenta que _parra_ tiene otras acepciones y que La Parra es un pueblo de Badajoz, al que podría hacer alusión el dicho. A fin de cuentas, _Babia_ también hace alusión a un lugar.